# Hyphen causing an error in laravel controller (unexpected = )?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following methods in my laravel controller that runs when my form is submitted:

```
public function validateSave() {
        $input = Request::all();
        $input->favicon = Request::has('favicon');
        $input->title = Request::has('title');
        $input->image-optimization = Request::has('image-optimization');
        QualityCheck::create($input);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Now when i submit the form i get the following Error in the frontEnd:

[image]

I am getting the error `unexpected "="` because i have a hypen(-) in my below line of code:

```
 $input->image-optimization = Request::has('image-optimization');
```

How do i overcome this error , i have already run my migration , and don't want to rollback and rename the feild , hence i am asking for a workaround ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `request()->all()` returns the array of inputs, you should get the item using `array keys` like this:

```
public function validateSave() {
  $inputs = Request::all();
  $inputs['favicon'] = Request::has('favicon');
  $inputs['title'] = Request::has('title');
  $inputs['image-optimization'] = Request::has('image-optimization');
  QualityCheck::create($inputs);
  return redirect('/');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: sure .. give me some time .. SO won't let me right now .